# Como omitir el alert de confirmación cuando recargo con la función location.reload()

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy construyendo un botón con la función  `onclick="location.reload()"`  y me funciona muy bien, lo único que quisiera omitir es que cuando le doy clic al botón me sale un `alert` predeterminado de Google:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y no deseo que me aparezca sino que recargue sin necesidad de confirmar este `alert`.

Este es mi código:

```
<!--START BUTTON BACK-->
<div class="ci-content">
    <div class="buttons-w">
        <a class="btn btn-secondary cancel-button close-prev-button" onclick="location.reload()" href="#"><img
                src="/agen/img/back.png">&nbsp;<span data-text-i18n=""></span>Volver a la conversación</a>
    </div>
</div>
<!--END BUTTON BACK-->
```

Probe añadiendole `onclick="location.reload(true)"`  me  funciono pero me muestra el siguiente alert:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No le doy en el checkbox porque lo van a probar desde otros navegadores y ya intente añadiendole el true pero no me funciono, muchisimas gracias por tu comentario. :D

Comment: Prueba redireccionando a la misma página `onclick="window.location.href"` o también con `onclick="window.location.href = window.location.href"`

Comment: Cris mira que me funciono con el ```onclick="location.reload(true)"``` pero me volvio aparecer otro alert. (Voy a modificar la pregunta y adjunto la imagen)

Comment: aver intenta con `onclick="window.location.assign(window.location.href)`

Comment: Tampoco me funciono :(